# Usage of indefinite article and too

Tags: articles, word-order

Is there any alternative to this construction?

> It was too stupid a question.

I mean, can we somehow put the 'a' in a different position and is it used in English (maybe informal) or the version I've given is the only possible?  Also, I feel as if something's wrong in my previous sentence, it would be very nice if anybody corrected it.

Comment: +1, _this_ question is certainly not stupid. Your example sentence is completely correct, but I am actually puzzled by the position of the article myself now :)

Comment: Somehow, the sentence sounds just fine to me (just like "too many a man" does). I'd say that "a too stupid question" is unlikely, though "a very stupid question" is quite common.

Comment: It gets worse! This one might be [*too hard **of** a question*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22too+hard+of+a+question%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for a definitive short answer!

Comment: As one of my college professors once said: "There is no such thing as a stupid question. It's just the people who ask them."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sentence,

> *It was too stupid a question.*

is good and correct. However, you can rephrase it if you'd like,

> *I thought (that) the question was too stupid.*
>   *Let's forget the question -- It was too stupid.*
>   NOT <del>*It was a too stupid question.*</del>

(Please see an excerpt from a grammar book below.)

---

From: *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan,

> **595 too**
>   **4 not used before adjective + noun**
>   *Too* is not normally used before **adjective + noun**.
>   　　*I put down the bag because it was too heavy.* (NOT ... <del>*the too heavy bag.*</del>)
>   ​　　*She doesn't like men who are too tall.* (NOT <del>*She doesn't like too tall men.*</del>)
>   ​　　*Let's forget this problem – it's too difficult.* (NOT ... <del>*this too difficult problem.*</del>)
>   In a rather formal style, too can be used before **adjective + a/an + noun** (see 14). Note the word order.
>   ​　　*It's **too cold a day** for tennis.*

Here is the entry 14 mentioned above:

> **14 adjectives (3): position after *as*, *how*, *so*, *too***
>   After *as*, *how*, *so*, *too* and *this/that* meaning *so*, adjectives go before *a/an*. This structure is common in a formal style.
>   ​　　*as/how/so/too/this/that* + adjective + *a/an* + noun
>   ​　　*I have **as good a voice** as you.*
>   ​　　*She is **too polite a person** to refuse.*
>   ​　　***How good a pianist*** is he?
>   ​　　*I couldn't afford **that big a car**.*
>   ​　　*It was **so warm a day** that I could hardly work.*
>   The structure is not possible without *a/an*.
>   ​　　*I like your country – it's so beautiful.* (NOT <del>*I like your so beautiful country*.</del>)
>   ​　　*Those girls are too kind to refuse.* (NOT <del>*They are too kind girls to refuse.*</del>)

Comment: PS. In my opinion, *too hard of a question* is of a different structure, though the meaning is similar to *too hard a question*.

Comment: Thank you for information. The only thing that bothers me is the last example. 'They are too kind girls to refuse' seems correct and logical for me, I can't do anything with it. I hope it isn't very serious mistake because I will probably make it during speaking.

Comment: I double checked the text, and it was written so. Though the book doesn't say it explicitly, I believe that it strongly suggests that only "too kind a girl" is the normal usage, not "too kind girls". In short, you need to rephrase it the way the book suggests.

Answer (score 3):

A question that was too stupid!!

This construction is common with *too* and *so*.

- too hard a job for me to do.
- so interesting a book to read
- too difficult a task to be carried out.
- so nice a girl to know.

Comment: +1 I'd add that it is not unheard of to say, "It was a too-stupid question." But "too stupid a question" is surely more common.

Comment: But "a too-stupid question" is, I think, nonstandard.

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, but I don't have the rep to comment.  The sentence sounds odd to me, because, to my ear, "too" needs to be explained -- too stupid to (or for) what?  "It was too stupid a question to waste time on."  "It was too stupid a question for most of the audience."  (I don't mean your question!)  Yes, the "a" sounds a bit odd, but it is OK.  What would definitely not be OK is "It was too stupid OF a question to waste time on."  This construction is seen far too often.

Comment: 'tis kinda late comment, but thanks for your addition anyway.