# "a so enjoyable party" or "so enjoyable a party"

Tags: comparative-constructions

I did some exercises on http://www.examenglish.com/ and did surprisingly pretty well. At a certain stage, the sentence mentioned in the title came by. Since I would of course say "*an enjoyable party*", I thought the same applies to the cases in which the adverb "*so*" becomes inserted. Brief overview:

> a very enjoyable party
>
> {article} {adverb} {adjective} {noun}

This evidently is correct.

> a so enjoyable party
>
> {article} {adverb} {adjective} {noun}

This sentence has the same structure as the foregoing one but is, according to the website, not correct.

1. Is "*a so enjoyable party*" also correct?
2. Is "*very enjoyable a party*" therefore also correct? Does it sound good to a native speaker?
3. What's the rationale behind this? The word classes are the same as I demonstrated above. Frankly speaking, I never read nor heard this kind of word order.

Comment: "such an enjoyable party" is an alternative to "a so enjoyable party" that sounds a lot more natural.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22354/3281.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*So* is traditionally classified as an ‘adverb’; but this is misleading. When it is used, as in your example, to modify an adjective or another adverb, it does not stand by itself but acts as a ‘pro-adverb’ (like a pro-noun) referring to another expression which defines its current meaning. In your example, for instance, *so enjoyable* ‘points’ to some expression which tells us *how* enjoyable the party was:

> The party was ***so***<sup>→</sup> enjoyable <sup>→</sup>[that I stayed much later than I intended]. *OR*
>   [I stayed much later than I intended]<sup>←</sup>, the party was <sup>←</sup>***so*** enjoyable.

You do find this complement omitted in exclamations:

> This party is ***so***<sup>→</sup> enjoyable <sup>→</sup>[_]!

The gap implies that the party is **so** enjoyable that words fail you! Your hearer is invited to ‘fill in the blank’ for herself with whatever comparison seems appropriate.

Note that these uses are all *predicative*: they fall in the predicate, after the verb *BE*. *So ADJ* cannot be employed to modify a bare nominal: it has to modify an entire noun phrase (NP), which includes the determiner. Consequently, if you want to use the expression *so ADJ* as an attributive modifier, next to the NP it modifies, it must come before or after the NP:

> <sup>ok</sup>It was ***so enjoyable*** [<sub>NP</sub> a party] that ... *OR*
>   <sup>ok</sup>It was [<sub>NP</sub> a party] ***so enjoyable*** that ... *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>∗</sup>  It was [<sub>NP</sub> a ***so enjoyable*** party] that ...

This ‘rule’ is so strong that if you want *so ADJ* to modify an NP which has no determiner—an indefinite plural for instance—you *must* put the expression *after* the NP.

> <sup>∗</sup> Mrs. Vanderhooven threw ***so enjoyable*** [<sub>NP</sub> parties] that ...

This is unacceptable; you must write:

> <sup>ok</sup>Mrs. Vanderhooven threw [<sub>NP</sub> parties] ***so enjoyable*** that ...

Alternatively, you may leave the *enjoyable* in front of the noun, incorporating it in the NP, and employ the ‘pro-adjective’ *such*, which behaves with NPs very similarly to the way *so* works with adjectives:

> <sup>ok</sup> Mrs. Vanderhooven threw ***such***<sup>→</sup> [<sub>NP</sub> enjoyable parties] [that ...

And this is in fact the construction that will ordinarily be used for exclamations:

> This is ***such***<sup>→</sup> an enjoyable party <sup>→</sup>[_]!

Comment: Excellent analysis of the ***so/such*** difference in this context! Like all native speakers, I know perfectly well we'd usually use ***such*** to create an NP suitable for use as a subject, etc. But I need your *pro-adverb/pro-adjective* distinction to understand *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the adjective is placed between indefinite article and noun ( a beautiful
day).

In special cases the adjective is placed before a/an, e. g.

so + adjective: so beautiful a day, so difficult a task

too + adjective: too difficult a task, too long a walk

There is also another pattern:

such: such a thrilling novel

quite: quite an old book