# ...so beautiful eyes.. Grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is it correct to write a noun after so + adjective like in this example 
**" She has so beautiful eyes".**

Comment: If you wanted to stick to that form it would be 'such' rather than 'so'

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22354/3281 (Phrases such as *so warm a day*, *so beautiful a girl*, *so gentle a man* are possible, but not \**so beautiful eyes*.)

Comment: But one can write *so, so beautiful* (which I thought this question was about, based on its title) and *oh so beautiful* as in *Her eyes are oh so beautiful.* Or *Her eyes are so, so beautiful.*, *The car is oh so fast* or *The car is so, so fast*.

Comment: I edited the duplicate "so" out of the Title, and changed tags ("so" is not a preposition; in OP's example it is adverbial, it modifies an adjective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So can be used as a degree adverb to mean very, extremely, or to such a great degree.  It's used in the pattern of so + adjective such as her eyes are so beautiful. It's incorrect to use eyes (noun) after so beautiful. Instead, you can use "such" in the pattern of such + adj + noun. For example, she has such beautiful eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You can write so + ADJ, however the sentence above is not correct grammar because someone cannot have 'so beautiful' anything. Your sentence above should be:

"Her eyes are so beautiful."

You can write 'so' + ADJ to describe what something is.

[EDIT]
Just felt that I needed to provide another example or two of when you can use 'so' + ADJ. Also, I forgot to mention in the original post -- Notice that 'so' is used before an adverb (adjective which describes a verb).

1) That car is so fast!

2) That car moves so quickly!

3) That car travelled so far!

Comment: Or "She has such beautiful eyes."