# such..that / so.. that

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's a sentence.

> Feeling flushed is ***such a natural response*** to sudden self-consciousness that if it weren't part of an emotionally crippling experience, it could almost be overlooked.

and can I rewrite like the following?

> Feeling flushed is ***so natural a response*** to sudden self-consciousness that if it weren't part of an emotionally crippling experience, it could almost be overlooked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"So [adjective] a [noun]" is a [valid](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40568246), though perhaps slightly old-fashioned, pattern. So yes, that rephrasing works.

See [Damkerng T's answer to a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22354/10820) with another citation.