# “as essential a part of the weekly shop”

Tags: grammar

**To the Dutch, milk and cheese are staples, as essential a part of the weekly shop as rice is for a Chinese shopper or teabags are for an Englishman.**

This is the sentence from CNN's one article. I don't understand why it is not "an essential part of the weekly shop".

Can you tell me about any rules or grammar in this phrase, please?

Comment: This is already posted on ELL as http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79319/ and it may be appropriate to merge the questions. The as/as comparison is not really on-topic on ELU.