# “Too natural an accident”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

> - The breaking of his jug was too **natural** an accident to excite suspicion.

What does natural function here, in the sentence?

Why is it not written this way: “a too natural accident”

My opinion, I think, is that “too natural” functioning as an adjective, but it is separated from “accident” to show some kind of emphasis.

What us your take on this case?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/usage-of-indefinite-article-and-too

Answer (score 1):

The word **too** is an adverb there (and **too**, to the best of my knowledge, can't be any other part of speech except an adverb unlike some other common adverbs and adjectives in English such as **fast**, for instance). Adverbs, as you probably know, modify adjectives, verbs and other adverbs. In this case, **too** modifies the adjective **natural**. It tells you how natural the accident was. It was too natural to excite suspicion.

The reason why it's not written any other way is because the way it's written in your example is how it's supposed to be written if we are to follow the rules of standard English grammar. What we're dealing here with is a very common grammar pattern in English that I think you definitely should commit to memory:

> **too** [adjective] **a**/**an** [countable noun] [some additional information]

This means exactly the same thing as **a**/**an** [adjective] [noun] with the exception that **too** would have to be substituted with something else—some other adverb such as **very**. I can't explain why, but the adverb **too**, for some reason, cannot be placed between an indefinite article and a noun. So, you can't really say **a too natural accident**. I think that's the reason why we have this pattern. Technically, the only thing that can be done with your example is to position **too natural** after **an accident**, but there's no reason to do that because it doesn't sound like a phrase you would ever actually hear someone use in this situation:

> The breaking of his jug was an accident **too natural** to excite suspicion.

A couple of examples:

> He was **too brave a man** not to take up the challenge. So, he entered the race and won it.
>
> I think she's **too good a woman** for me. A loser like me just can't marry someone like her.